# Alpha texture images appear lighter than the original image

Tags: texturing, shaders, image, transparency

I drew a cube in the 2D drawing tool and printed it out as a png file, and imported it into the blender using the `Shift + A, Images as Planes` function.
But here is the problem.
The imported image is lighter than the original image.

Please see the attached screenshot.
The image opened in Paint on the right is the original.
The Reference object next to it accurately displays the original image.
However, the three `Image as Planes` objects on the left are displayed lightly.

Perhaps the texture responds to the environment, but I wonder if even objects with shadeless and emit options react to the environment.
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

To help you write your answer, I have uploaded a blend file containing png images.
[image]

---

**Screenshot for additional questions about Leander's answer :**
The Color Mnagement> View Transform> Raw option causes the black and white alpha textures to appear the same as the original image, but for color images, the colors appear darker.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to undo the viewtransform. E.g. if you switch to *RAW* via the Properties > Colormanagement >View Transform, the images display the same as the reference.

Comment: @Leander
That method has its limitations.
Of course, the RAW option displays the cube picture the same as the original image, but darker for other color images.
I have attached a new screenshot in the text.
Please check.